# Deleting duplicate text from a chapter

Tags: python

I am currently learning python and SQL Postgres. I have this text file with 30 chapters, and the content of the chapter is duplicated. Each chapter has a unique name, only the content of the chapter is duplicated and I am trying to get rid of the dups. It looks like

> Input

```
Chapter 1:Learning to think
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM (all content in chapter 1)
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM (content repeat) 
Chapter 2:Stopping your thoughts
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX (all content in chapter 2)
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX (content repeat)
...etc
```

> Output

```
Chapter 1:Learning to think
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM (all content in chapter 1)
Chapter 2:Stopping your thoughts
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX (all content in chapter 2)
...etc
```

The goal is to remove the additional content with python code. I was thinking about creating a loop that would create a string of each chapter then I would store the first sentence in a variable and delete anything until the first sentence repeated. Is there a simpler way?
My mind is exploding and I am not sure how to code that.
Thank you
additional edits:
I am not sure how to put each chapter into a dictionary as {Chapter 1:Learning to think: content in chapter 1} as I am not sure to delimit it.

Comment: If you create a string from the whole chapter, then you should be able to just cut that string in half, right?  Or is there extra stuff beyond the duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't remove like that while operating over a file, instead what you can do is to store each chapters in a dictionary and remove the additional content from the dictionary and write the remaining non-duplicate contents to a new file, like this...

```py
# Reading Data from file
with open("sample.txt") as file:
    data = file.readlines()

chapters, i, chapter, temp = dict(), 1, data[0], tuple()

# Splitting data based on Chapters
while i<len(data):
    if "Chapter" not in data[i]:
        temp += (data[i],)
    else:
        if any(temp):
            chapters[chapter] = tuple(temp)
            chapter = data[i]
            temp = tuple()
    i+=1

# Inverting chapters to eliminate redundant contents
inv_chapters = {key:val for val, key in sorted(chapters.items(), reverse=True)}

# Inverting again to restore the original structure
res = {inv_chapters[key]:key for key in inv_chapters}

# Writing the new data to a new output file
with open("out.txt", "w") as file1:
    for i in res:
        file1.writelines(tuple(i)+res[i])

print("Output written to file...")
```

Output:-

```
Output written to file...
Executed in 0.0003762245178222656 seconds
```

sample.txt

```
Chapter 1:Learning to think
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
Chapter 2:Stopping your thoughts
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
Chapter 3:abcd
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
Chapter 4:Stopping your thoughts
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
Chapter 5:Learning to think
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
Chapter 6:Stopping your thoughts
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
Chapter 7:Learning to think
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
Chapter 8:Stopping your thoughts
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
```

out.txt

```
Chapter 1:Learning to think
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
MXMXMXMXMXMXXM
Chapter 2:Stopping your thoughts
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
NXNXNXNXNXNXNX
```

Explanation :-
Here, the `data` variable holds all the lines of the file without grouping them into chapters, then the `while` loop iterates through it and groups them into their respective chapters in the format `{"Chapter Heading":"Content"}` and stores them in the `chapters` dictionary; then the `inv_chapters` inverts the dictionary so as to eliminate all the redundant chapters and finally the `res` inverts the `inv_chapters` dictionary so as to restore back the structure of the original dictionary and the `for` loop writes it to the output file.

Comment: I am sorry I think  I did not express myself correctly. 1. Can I ask for you to clarify your code? I think I understand some parts, but others are still confusing, and I am not sure what the output represents 2. I will edit my first post to present what I want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is much clearer for me now.

Comment: You're always welcome!!!